# Java typecasting from extended

Tags: java, types, casting, extends

I have the following code:

```
public static <T extends User> void addUser(String username,
        String passwordHash, Class<T> userClass, File usersDir) {

    T user = (T) new User(username, passwordHash);
    UserManager.toFile(user, usersDir);
}
```

Eclipse gives me the following warning:

`Type safety: Unchecked cast from User to T`

Why do I get the warning that it's not checked if i defined **T** to extend User with `<T extends User>`

Comment: Because you can't downcast like that regardless if you're using generics or not? Unless `T` *is* `User` it's invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding generics.

`T extends User` doesn't mean that `T` **is** `User`; it means that `T` can be any class that inherits `User`.

If `T` is `FunkyUser`, your code won't work.

Comment: I'm using this now: `T user2 = userClass.cast(new BaseUser(username, passwordHash));`. Is this better? (BTW, i'll accept your answer in 5 minutes, when noob-protection allows me to ¬¬)

Comment: With that code I don't get the warning anymore. What's the difference?

Comment: @TwinOneAndroid - you don't get the warning because that checks the cast and will throw an exception if you pass anything but `User.class` ... which goes back to `T extends User` making no sense because you can't do that. Your original way wouldn't blow up until you actually tried to use `user`

Answer (score 2):

`T` can be any extending class of `User`. You're instantiating a new `User`, i.e. the super class. So, if `T` isn't **exactly** the `User` type (i.e. a subclass), the cast is unsafe and a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Comment: The cast isn't illegal so much as its *unsafe*.

Comment: @Perception IMHO, it's not an safe/unsafe stuff, since a `ClassCastException` will be whatever thrown if `T` is a subclass, am I wrong?

Comment: in this context, an *illegal* cast is one which would be caught by the compiler, whereas an *unsafe* one can result in a run time exception (in this case, a `ClassCastException`).

Comment: @Perception Interesting, I didn't get this shade, thank you `;)` I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum T can be a User , actually it can be also AdvancedUser

```
class AdvancedUser extends User{}
```

Then your program will fail if You declare the T as an advanced user because You're upcasting the real User object to AdvancedUser type. Therefore it gives You a warning about unsafe cast